# Show image in PictureBox from DB

Tags: vb.net

When I retrieve an object from my DB, I try to do this:

```
Dim pictureBytes As New MemoryStream(imagen.JugFir)
pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(pictureBytes)
```

But I get an error:

> 'imagen.JugFir' is an Object and `Image.FromStream()` requires a `Byte[]`.

How i can convert `Object` to `Byte[]` ?

Or is there any other way to load the picture?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28638303/4904569

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to store and retrieve images in sql server database with vb.net using picturebox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10267993/how-to-store-and-retrieve-images-in-sql-server-database-with-vb-net-using-pictur)

Comment: What is the type of `imagen.JugFir`? Is it an Image type?  Where does it come from? What is the data type of the Field where you store your Images? Add the missing code, where you *acquire* the Image data.

Comment: Have you tried making a direct cast to a `byte[]` at all?